# How to update db according to the changes of C# DataGridView?

Tags: c#, database, datagridview

I have a DataGridView and a save button on one of my forms. Users can edit the data in the gridview (data comes from a database) and I want to update the database on save button clicking with the user edited data. How can I do it?

Comment: Which database are you using??? i.e SQL,MSACCESS etc...which one?

Comment: @Kyle I'm using Access 2010 database.

Comment: what you have tried.? please share

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your Save Button click event

```
    private void SaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
     System.Data.DataTable dsnew = ((DataView)gridView1.DataSource).Table;
    }
```

This will get your gridview into dataset

Once you get data in your dataset you can perform your necessary **Update** or **Insert** Query

Answer (score 1):

Also, remember to terminate any current edit that the user is doing.

```
gridView1.EndEdit();
((DataRowView)gridView1.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem).EndEdit();
```

The first line is usually enough, but when you have the DataGridView object bound to a DataView, you need the second line to force the underlying DataTable to update.